# Produce time series plots for each name pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have a Pandas data frame `df` that looks like this:

```
       date                 A      B        name
 2022-06-25 04:00:00       700     532        aa
 2022-06-25 05:00:00      1100     433        aa
 2022-06-25 06:00:00       800     754        aa
 2022-06-25 07:00:00      1200     288        aa
 2022-06-25 08:00:00       700     643        bb
 2022-06-25 09:00:00      1400     668        bb
 2022-06-25 10:00:00      1600     286        bb
                     .....
 2022-06-03 11:00:00       397      46        cc
 2022-06-03 12:00:00       100       7        cc
 2022-06-03 13:00:00       400      25        cc
 2022-06-03 14:00:00       500      41        cc
 2022-06-03 15:00:00       400       0        cc
 2022-06-03 16:00:00       300      23        dd
 2022-06-03 17:00:00       500      50        dd
 2022-06-03 18:00:00       300       0        dd
 2022-06-03 19:00:00       400      15        dd
```

I'm trying to Produce time series plots for each name. Line charts.
number of daily A vs date
number of daily B vs date

I was able to do so and get a plot for each name like this:

```
df.groupby('name').plot(x='date', figsize=(24,12))
```

But I couldn't specify a title for each plot like this `plt.title(" ")`
And also couldn't auto save each plot like this `plt.savefig('name.png')`
Because they all produce at once.

Is there any other way to produce plots so I can specify the title and save each plot automatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to do what you require is to put the code for your plot creation and plot save inside a for loop. That will allow you to add a title using the `title`. Also, you will be able to use `savefig` to individually save each of the plots. The update code and one of the output graphs is shown below. Note that I am adding `name` as the title and saving the figure as `Myplot <name>.png`

```
for name, group in df.groupby('name'):
    group.plot(x='date', title=name)
    plt.savefig('Myplot {}.png'.format(name), bbox_inches='tight')
```

**First plot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked for me. appreciate your answer